SpringBoot 3 application does not creating traceId and spanId when micrometer dependency is referred from another project
I'm trying to generate traceId and spanId in my application. However I've kept io.micrometer dependency in another common module (which does not have main). when I use common-modules jar in my application though it downloads micrometer dependency but it does not generate traceId and spanId. But when I'm specifically adding the dependency in my application it generates traceId and spanId.
I'm using below micrometer dependency along with actuator
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-observation</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
  </dependency>

I want micrometer dependency to be in common modules so that I don't have to repeat these dependency in my subcomponents.

Probably micrometer jars are not on your classpath and Micrometer has nothing to do with your issue (please check your classpath). You might want to take a look at maven's parent pom feature to include dependencies in your subproject.
